# Matlab Line Highlighter tool to profile inefficient lines?

Tags: matlab, profiling

Eclipse with Java had some profiling tool that highlighted the lines according to the times of running certain lines. Is there something like that for Matlab? I am trying to find lines with most running, how can I do it with Matlab?

**Update 1**

> This is the profiler's window but I cannot understand where I should click for getting color highlighting. I asked the same question [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76448-matlab-how-to-profile-inefficient-lines-of-code-with-running-count-visualisation#answer_86103) but closed it because SO worked far better, thank you for your help!
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab profiler does exactly what you want.

If a line of code is during a run of profiler the code will light up (black on white, instead of gray on white) and the more time is spent on this line of code the more the background of this line will turn blue (via 50 shades of blue:) ).

```
profile clear
profile on
ver
profile off
profile viewer
```

In the profile viewer you click on `ver` and then in the combobox below select for: Color highlight code according to: `numcalls`

[image]

[image]

Please check out the documentation for [`profile`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).

Comment: @hhh click on ver... then you will get another screen. In the lower part of the screen you'll find the Dropdown (combobox).

Comment: @hhh by clicking on a hyperlink (in this case `ver`) in the profile summary as you show in your picture

Comment: @hhh it is on your screen... in blue you see `ver`... it's clickable, underneath it is `ver>getAllToolboxInfo`... you might want to undock your window for this.

Comment: Thank you, really helped -- I did not realize to look below at the blue things.

Answer (score 0):

After running `profile on`, the profile sets some environment variables such as NumCals mentioned by Nick. I don't know yet how to visualize them but this [page](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/matlab_prog/ch7_pe26.html) helps to use it and below an example about getting execution counts per line and amount of function calls.

```
profile on -history % history not enabled by default

p=profile('info');

% Some code here...

% I don't know yet any good way to visualise them but here datadumps
p.FunctionTable.ExecutedLines 
p.FunctionTable.NumCalls
```